# how bootstrap colors works?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i'm trying to practice using bootstrap these days and i want to understand everything in the code but there's something i don't understand which is the **navbar colors** as you see below when i put **the navbar-dark** class the navbar doesn't display with a dark color but it's displayed whith a white color and when i put the **"navbar-light" class** it will be diplayed with a grey color i'm struggling with this problem please if anybody can help me i will be so thankful

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TinDog</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <section id="title">

    <!-- Nav Bar --> <!---->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
    <!--why when i put the navbar-dark class the navbar doesn't display with a dark color but it's displayed whith a white color and when i put the "navbar-light" class it will be diplayed with a grey color i'm struggling with this problem please if anybody can help me i will be so thankful-->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">tindog</a>
         <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">contact us</a>
            </li>
             <li>
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">pricing</a>
            </li>
             <li>
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">download</a>
            </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.navbar-dark` changes the text color of anchor elements inside the navbar.

You need to apply `bg-dark` to override the default color of the navbar.

[Navbar link](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_navbar.asp)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TinDog</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <section id="title">

    <!-- Nav Bar --> <!---->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <!--why when i put the navbar-dark class the navbar doesn't display with a dark color but it's displayed whith a white color and when i put the "navbar-light" class it will be diplayed with a grey color i'm struggling with this problem please if anybody can help me i will be so thankful-->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">tindog</a>
         <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">contact us</a>
            </li>
             <li>
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">pricing</a>
            </li>
             <li>
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">download</a>
            </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: I addede OP code ... for more clear about what to do